# nodetool repair fails with snapshot error

Tags: cassandra

When running nodetool repair, the repair fails on the system_auth keyspace with the following log entries:

```
INFO  [AntiEntropySessions:5] 2015-03-17 20:00:34,795 RepairSession.java:260 - [repair #460cebb0-cce0-11e4-ba34-299132139fb9] new session: will sync <list of hosts and ips> on range (-7227533065400353128,-7224188466775720910] for system_auth.[credentials, users]
ERROR [AntiEntropySessions:1] 2015-03-17 20:00:34,800 RepairSession.java:303 - [repair #3f7e2610-cce0-11e4-ba34-299132139fb9] session completed with the following error
java.io.IOException: Failed during snapshot creation.
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.failedSnapshot(RepairSession.java:344) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairJob$2.onFailure(RepairJob.java:146) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1172) ~[guava-16.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

The error repeats every few seconds until I restart the cassandra service. On the other hand, if I do `nodetool snapshot system_auth`, the operation succeeds (with no log entries).

My cassandra version is 2.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

We have similar issues in Cassandra 2.1.5.

You can try running:

```
nodetool scrub system_auth
```

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8696 increasing the value of `request_timeout_in_ms` in cassandra.yaml might help, too (they plan to change the timeout value used for `nodetool repair` in Cassandra 2.1.6 and newer).